# Two-Factor Authentication is not working: SMS is not reaching me

Tags: authentication, verification

When trying to log in to Mailchimp it says that I would get a SMS with a verification code. I don't get this SMS. Which means I can't log in. What can I do?

Comment: thank you. I am happy that today it worked again, i got the SMS. I will make sure that I turn off the Two-Factor Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This recently happened to me. Contact Mailchimp directly via email and they will be able to bypass the two factor authentication for you and allow you to login and turn it off.